# MySQL error while uploading large CSV data set

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I've got the below code snippet which works fine when I try to upload a CSV file with relatively smaller (~500) entries. However when the entries get larger (I tried 20,000) it triggers the following error.

> You have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'S FANCY-KNDY0046','1298','32321','QE4224','2')' at line 1

My `INSERT into` looks like this: (Haven't really thought of sanitizing the input here yet but your thoughts would come in handy too!)

```
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
         while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
           $sql = "INSERT into universe (`zone`, `area`, `sub`) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(!$result )
                {
                    echo "ERROR:". mysqli_error($conn); // I included this to see the error message.
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                            window.location = \"index.php\"
                        </script>";
            }
         }
         fclose($file);
         echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                    window.location = \"index.php\"
                </script>"; 
        mysqli_close($conn); 
     }
```

Appreciate if someone can point me if I'm doing something wrong here! Thank you.

Comment: add your whole error message here `You have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near..`

Comment: Might there be special characters in the larger file that aren't escaped properly?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR added the whole line as requested. What you see there is the actual data getting inserted.

Comment: check the data in your csv file just before the `S FANCY-KNDY0046`, may be there is some special characters which causes terminating the query. possibaly a quote(')

Comment: If you started to use prepared statements and bind variables, you would most likely see this problem disappear as quotes etc will cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR looks like sanitization gonna help me mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply you have a `'` in the string that you are wrapping with `''` and therefore the string is being broken early and causing a syntax error.

If you were using parameterised queries this would not have any effect on the query, and you would be protecting yourself from [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    // prepare the query once and reuse lots of times
    // reduces load on the server as well as the database
    // only has to compile and optimize the query once
    $sql = "INSERT into universe (`zone`, `area`, `sub`) 
            VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $emapData[0], $emapData[1], $emapData[2]);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        if(!$result ) {
            echo "ERROR:". $conn->error; // I included this to see the error message.
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                  window.location = \"index.php\"
                  </script>";
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
          alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
          window.location = \"index.php\"
          </script>"; 
 }
```

Comment: Yes! that makes a lot of sense to query once and reuse multiple times. Thank you. This helps!